# how to make a button visible / invisible in an if else loop

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm building an android app (similar to Discord for those who know it). All channels are displayed on the homepage, each channel has attributes (name, author, mine; what I have to do is display a DETAILS button only next to my channels (and therefore if the mine attribute is equal to "t").
The problem is that if I write **b.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE)** or **b.setVisibility (View.GONE)** the whole line disappears and therefore also the channel name.

Main Activity:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < canaliJSON.length(); i ++){ 
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) canaliJSON.get(i); 
                String title = obj.getString("ctitle");
                String property = obj.getString("mine");

                final Button buttonHv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hv);
                View b = findViewById(R.id.hv);
                        if (property.equals("t")) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"myChannel");
                            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.d(TAG,"not myChannel");
                            buttonHv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                canali.add(new Canale(title, property + " "+ buttonHv));
            }
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <!--Nome canale nella homepage-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/canale_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
        android:text="HV" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As an aside why you are you assigning the same view to both a button and a view? 
`  final Button buttonHv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hv);
                View b = findViewById(R.id.hv);` just use the button when showing/hiding

Comment: View.GONE basically sets the width and height to 0, so it's possible that your layout just collapses, you should try .`setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` instead. just note that you might want to disable the view as well

Comment: Is this sorted out?

Comment: @DevWithZachary 
it was just a test, but even using only the button the whole line, including the channel name, continues to disappear

Comment: @Piyush Not yet..

Comment: @DevWithZachary I tried with INVISIBLE but it keeps disappearing all the line (including the channel name)

Comment: So your logic is working properly? You just have UI visibility issue? Also your code confusing.

Comment: @Piyush yes, the log is printed correctly, it is the display that is incorrect

Comment: Remove _View b = findViewById(R.id.hv);_.  Change `b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` to `buttonHv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. Also `buttonHv.setVisibility(View.GONE);` to `buttonHv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` @SaraFrau

Comment: @SaraFrau Checked?

Comment: @Piyush 
I did, and now it gives me this error: W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference(the channel list is gone and the page is blank)

Comment: Declare `final Button buttonHv` global and remove `final` keyword. Initialize `buttonHv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hv);` in _onCreate()_

Answer (score 0):

Why you have declared the button 2 times with 'View' and 'Button'?
Just use 'Button'

Remove this line from your code:
`View b = findViewById(R.id.hv);`

And use:
`buttonHv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

'View' will get all the elements including 'Button' or any other tags you have used. Just use 'Button'